# Как на Vue добавить картинку в background-image через импорт

Tags: vue.js

Есть компонент на Vue, где у меня импортированы картинки:

```
<script setup>
import backgroundDesktop from "./../assets/images/bg-shorten-desktop.svg";
import backgroundMobile from "./../assets/images/bg-shorten-mobile.svg";
</script>

<template>
  <div class="shorter">
    <input type="text" class="shorter__input">
    <button class="shorten__button">Shorten It!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "./../assets/colors/color.scss";

.shorter {
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: $darkViolet;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url('./../assets/images/bg-shorten-desktop.svg');
}
</style>
```

Для примера, в `background-image` я задал url той же картинки, которая отображается на сайте. Как мне это сделать через импорт? Тоесть чтобы путь в url был `backgroundDesktop`, который импортировал.

Comment: А зачем вам в Style делать? Получайте адрес в переменную любым способом - например в const img555=ref(null) и выводите в компоненте спокойно что хотите через :style="'background-image::' img555"

Answer (score 0):

Заводим в корне переменную --background-image

```css
:root {
    --background-image: '';
}
.shorter {
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: $darkViolet;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: var(--background-image);
}
```

В нужном месте скриптом меняем её значение

```js
document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--background-image', "url('./../assets/images/bg-shorten-desktop.svg')");
```

Comment: Это не совсем то что я имел ввиду. Мне надо чтобы оно выглядело примерно так: "background-image: url('${backgroundDesktop}');", или что-то похожее...

Comment: Хотя у вас всё лежит в одном файле, после бильда это всё разнесётся по разным, поэтому передавать информацию придётся из js в css. Vue не умеет делать реактивные css, поэтому передавать информацию придётся самому. Я описал метод, который это делает. После рендеринга компонента просто меняйте переменную в css - автоматически поменяется фон. Это тоже своего рода реактивность в css.